# Logical OR in GLOB during grep --include/--exclude

Tags: bash, grep

In the Ubuntu terminal, I would like to `grep` all files with (or excluding) extension `.foo` and `.bar` for the phrase `'foobar'`.

I've read [this advice](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/016) for creating a `GLOB` with a logical or, and tried a few combinations but none seem to work:

```
rgrep "foobar" --include "*.foo|*.bar"
rgrep "foobar" --include "*.{foo,bar}"
rgrep "foobar" --exclude "(*.foo|*.bar)"
```

What's the secret recipe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `extglob` pattern here:

```
shopt -s extglob
grep 'foobar' *.@(foo|bar)
```

---

For using **recursive grep** with `--include` you have to use **GLOB** patterns only:

```
grep -R 'foobar' --include=*.{foo,bar} .
```

Comment: This works, but is it possible to use this with `--exclude` as well as `--include`? (as per the title of the OP; I'll also update the question to reflect this)

Comment: Added an answer for `--include` pattern.